# Need to upgrade typescript compiler `tsc` version to 3.0

Tags: node.js, typescript

How to upgrade `tsc` version to 2.62

> currently i'm using 1.5.3 version

Comment: You are probably confusing the compiler (tsc) version and the language (typescript) version. tsc -v prints the _compiler_ version.

Answer (score 0):

Use following npm command to update

Updating to specific version

```
npm install -g typescript@3.0
```

or

```
npm update -g typescript@3.0
```

For more read [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript)

Comment: I am new to typescript and curious to learn.. I have question? is typescript version and typescript compiler version are updated through same command. because I believe OP asked about typescript compiler and your answer is more about updating typescript version

Comment: Thanks for reply But I already use this command my typescript version changes to 3.0 but tsc version not changes I retain the sane 1.5.3 version